# How to use defined variable(defined in php file) in .js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a config.php file in which I defined a variable `SITE(define('SITE',"siteroot")` and I have a .js file which included jquery functions. In that file, I have a variable `site_root`.

Is it possible I can make  `site_root=<?=SITE?>`

I change the .js file to php file and used this code `header("Content-type: application/javascript");` to defined the type of the file and include the config file. However,  `site_root=<?=SITE?` return `""`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have a typo in the question or in the actual code, but

```
define('SITE',"siteroot");
```

and

```
var site_root = "<?= SITE ?>";
//              ^           ^ quotes matter
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Declare PHP Variable**

```
<?php 
$variable = "abc";
?>

<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
var test = "<?php echo  $variable; ?>";
alert(test);
});
</script>
```